# JAVA HandShake_failure : Certificates, SSLContext, KeyStore, card reader

Tags: java, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate, handshake

I am totally lost on one thing : SSL and JAVA
In fact, i always come back to the same error: "handshake_failure".
This problem appears at the begining of the week. There is a pem file which has been updated. There are 6 certificates which have been added to the file. 
They come from a card reader that create an authentication system.
In order to create a correct binding between the server and the client, i use this code:

```
X509Certificate certificat = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(CERTIFICAT_AUTHENTIFICATION_CPS);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(keyStore, null);
            KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();             
           KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            ks.load(null, null);
            ks.setCertificateEntry(Integer.toString(1), certificat);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
```

The parameter CERTIFICAT_AUTHENTIFICATION_CPS is the good one (verified).

Nevertheless, when i launch an https request (SPRING and REST system), i get the following handshake error with -Djavax.net.debug=all:

```
Caused by: fr.appli.business.commons.exception.BusinessException: fr.appli.rest.communication.commons.exception.RestException: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://www.url.com/web_local": Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at fr.appli.business.interceptor.BusinessInterceptor.rethrowExceptionOnBusinessServiceOperation(BusinessInterceptor.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at fr.appli.data.repositories.model.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.logExecutionTime(AbstractInterceptor.java:20)
at fr.appli.business.interceptor.BusinessInterceptor.logExecutionTime(BusinessInterceptor.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.getUtilisateurByCpxId(Unknown Source)
at fr.appli.business.authentification.AuthentificationServiceImpl.connect(AuthentificationServiceImpl.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at fr.appli.business.interceptor.BusinessInterceptor.rethrowExceptionOnBusinessServiceOperation(BusinessInterceptor.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at fr.appli.data.repositories.model.interceptor.AbstractInterceptor.logExecutionTime(AbstractInterceptor.java:20)
at fr.appli.business.interceptor.BusinessInterceptor.logExecutionTime(BusinessInterceptor.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.connect(Unknown Source)
at fr.appli.ui.manager.authentification.AuthentificationUIManager.connect(AuthentificationUIManager.java:37)
at fr.appli.ui.manager.authentification.AuthentificationUIManager.connect(AuthentificationUIManager.java:32)
at fr.appli.ui.manager.cardreader.CpxCardUIManager.connect(CpxCardUIManager.java:63)
at fr.appli.ui.dialog.DialogPasswordInputController.dpiConfirmate(DialogPasswordInputController.java:68)
... 78 common frames omitted
```

Could you give me some help please ?

Vinz

Comment: We don't see anything interesting in your log , try -Djavax.net.debug=ssl instead and come back .

Comment: Please, firstly could you tell me if i use the good operation in order to add a public key to the application ? (Keystore + keymanagerfactory + the adding thanks to openssl.init(...) method) ?

Comment: load(null, null), what are you trying to do with that ? Read 
Example 1: Creating an SSLEngine object  from the official doc : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#SSLEngine

Comment: I am tryinh to create the correct client side (retrieve the public key from the hard reader) which will permits to allows the requests https which home from the server. I must retrieve the certificat which is in the card reader. I am going to read the doc. Thanks you.